# Mysql Multiple joins from 4 tables

Tags: mysql

I need to list all the poetry from users that check in for the night.  I have a custom table and use wordpress.

I have a table called **checkin** with a field called **ID** which is the wordpress users id. I also have a filed called **date**, which is a timestamp.

The poems get stored in the '**wp0k_posts**' table, The user again is stored as **ID**. I need to grab of course the '**post_content**' and '**post_title**' where the '**post_type**' is equal to '**um_story**'.

The real difficult part is that wordpress stores the users first name and last name in a separate table called **wp0k_usermeta**. **user_id** is equal to **wp0k_users.ID**. the store the values like so filed "**first_name**" = "Jim", "**last_name**" = "Harris"

I'm hoping to return:
wp0k_users.ID | wp0k_usermeta.first_name | wp0k_usermeta.last_name | wp0k_posts.post_title | wp0k_posts. post_content
Where checkin.date == Today

Comment: The question is too confusing as you are trying to elaborate a table. Use a diagram or SQLFiddle instead by building schemas.

Comment: SQL Select queries for Wordpress may appear complex at first due to the "flexible" "object model" employed by Wordpress. Try reading this https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query there are many similar sources

Comment: Ok... I started up a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2825d/2.  I am super bad at joins, so this doesn't seem to have any or need?  Not sure.

what I'm missing is digging into the usermeta table to get their first name and last name.

Ie... people can check into show.  This SQL checks to see if they have submitted poetry.

This sql will display all users and all poetry they submitted (post_title and post_content).

I can't seem to get my head around how to dig into the wp0k_usermeta to include their first name and lastname

Comment: added a check to make sure the post_type = um_story
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2825d/5/0

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question it looks like all of the table have connection to `wp0k_user` table . Your table naming is so confusing but here is what I've tried so far. If you could edit your question with more explanation then we could help further. :

```
select wu.id,wum.first_name, wum.last_name,wp.post_title,wp.post_content
from wp0k_users wu join wp0k_posts  wp on wp.user_id = wu.id
join wp0k_usermetadata wum on wum.user_id=wu.id
join checkin c on c.user_id=wu.id
where c.date >= CURDATE();
```